# python style guide by google - clarification on properties

Tags: python

## Question

Please elaborate on the Goolge Python Stile Guide on properties:

> Inheritance with properties can be **non-obvious** if the property itself is not overridden

> ensure methods overridden in subclasses are called by the property

1. What does **non-obvious** mean and what are potential issues?
2. What does **ensure overridden method to be called by property** mean and what are potential issues?

[Google Python Style Guide 2.13 Properties](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#2134-decision)

> 2.13.4 Decision
> Inheritance with properties can be **non-obvious if the property itself is not overridden**. Thus one must make sure that accessor methods are called indirectly **to ensure methods overridden in subclasses are called by the property** (using the template method design pattern).

```
import math

     class Square:
         """A square with two properties: a writable area and a read-only perimeter.

         To use:
         >>> sq = Square(3)
         >>> sq.area
         9
         >>> sq.perimeter
         12
         >>> sq.area = 16
         >>> sq.side
         4
         >>> sq.perimeter
         16
         """

         def __init__(self, side):
             self.side = side

         @property
         def area(self):
             """Area of the square."""
             return self._get_area()

         @area.setter
         def area(self, area):
             return self._set_area(area)

         def _get_area(self):
             """Indirect accessor to calculate the 'area' property."""
             return self.side ** 2

         def _set_area(self, area):
             """Indirect setter to set the 'area' property."""
             self.side = math.sqrt(area)

         @property
         def perimeter(self):
             return self.side * 4
```

Answer (score 1):

What's non-obvious is that when you inherit from the class you have to take special consideration of how you override properties in the subclass, because the definition may be spread between multiple methods.

If you define a subclass of `Square` that implements the `area` property differently, you need to do either:

1. Ensure that the `Square._get_area()` and `Square._set_area()` methods are never called directly, only through the property methods. Then you can define new properties in the subclass.
2. Override the `_get_area()` and `_set_area()` methods in the subclass. Then it's not necessary to redefine the properties -- they'll be inherited normally, but will call the internal methods of the subclass.

Neither of these is complicated, but it's something extra you may have to check for when inheriting from a class with properties.

Comment: I don't see an answer to question 1. Why is inheritance with properties non-obvious? If you don't explain this, there's not any reason to introduce `_get_area` and `_set_area` in the first place.

Comment: It's non-obvious because you have to notice the relationship between the properties and the internal methods. I thought that was obvious from the rest of the answer.